# R (Error): Evaluation of vectorized objective function returned a malformed matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, function, optimization

I am working with the R programming language. I am using the "mco" library to perform "constrained multi-objective optimization" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mco/mco.pdf)

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(mco)

# create some data for this example
    a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
    b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
    c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
    train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

I defined the following function that I want to optimize (7 inputs, 4 outputs):

```
#define function

funct_set <- function (x) {
    x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3] ; x4 <- x[4]; x5 <- x[5]; x6 <- x[6]; x[7] <- x[7]
    f <- numeric(4)
    
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>%
        mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x1 & b1 <= x3, "a",
                            ifelse(a1 <= x2 & b1 <= x4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    
    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[5],1,0 )))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[6],1,0 )))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[7],1,0 )))
    
    f[1] = mean(table_a$quant)
    f[2] = mean(table_b$quant)
    f[3] = mean(table_c$quant)
    
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    # calculate the total mean 
    
    f[4] = mean(final_table$quant)
    
#count number of rows in each table
n5 = data.frame(table_a %>% 
  summarise(count = n()))

n6 = data.frame(table_b %>% 
  summarise(count = n()))

n7 = data.frame(table_c %>% 
  summarise(count = n()))



    
    return (f);
}
```

Next, I defined a series of constraints:

```
gn <- function(x) {
    g1 <- x[3] - x[1] 
    g2<- x[4] - x[2] 
    g3 <- x[7] - x[6]
    g4 <- x[6] - x[5] 
 g5 <- n5 > 20
 g6 <- n6 > 20
 g7 <- n7 > 20
    return(c(g1,g2,g3,g4, g5, g6, g7))
}
```

Finally, I ran the optimization algorithm (idim = input dimension, odim = output dimension, cdim = dimension of the constraints)

```
optimization <- nsga2(funct_set, idim = 7, odim = 4 , constraints = gn, cdim = 7,
                      
                      generations=150,
                      popsize=100,
                      cprob=0.7,
                      cdist=20,
                      mprob=0.2,
                      mdist=20,
                      lower.bounds=rep(80,80,80,80, 100,200,300),
                      upper.bounds=rep(120,120,120,120,200,300,400)
)
```

**Problem:** Unfortunately, this produces an error:

```
Evaluation of vectorized objective function returned a malformed matrix. Expected 4 rows and 100 columns but got 7 rows and 100 columns.
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced? Is it because the "gn" object can not accept inputs such as "n5, n6, n7"?

Thanks

Comment: It says it was expecting a matrix. This: `c(g1,g2,g3,g4, g5, g6, g7)` is not a matrix.

Comment: thank you! do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: What I do is read error messages as carefully as I can and then open the help page for the function and review the examples and paste them into my console. If that works", i.e. no errors, I go back and forth between my code and the successful example until I come up with an idea of ways to correct the situation. Sometimes I then open up the code of the function to see what lines of code are triggering the error or run R in browser mode.

Comment: It also appears you switched from a bunch of `n`'s to a single indexed `f[.]` but failed to complete the conversion in your first function. (ALSO note that you cannot keep logicals and numerics in the same vector of matrix. They will all become numeric. AND why would `x[3] - x[1] ` be a "constraint"?

Comment: After looking at the package documentation which was very skimpy and had no vignettes, I can say for sure that I will be of no further help. The "constraints used in examples are all built as functions that return numeric values which doesn't fulfill my definition of a constraint so apparently they are being used differently that my understanding supports. But not documentation is apparent. If this is is for a class then perhaps you have been given something better?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I got a similar question to work the other day : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348399/specifying-logical-conditions-e-g-greater-than-and-less-than-in-r ... the code here is similar. In this current question, I am trying to add a few more constraints but its not working. i will keep trying